# Using bash to sort data horizontally

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a file full of data in columns

```
sarah mark john
10    20   5
x     y    z
```

I want to sort the data so the columns stay intact but the second row is in increasing order so it looks like this:

```
john sarah mark
5    10    20 
z    x     y
```

I've been looking at the sort command but have only been able to find vertical sorting, not horizontal. I'm happy to use any tool, any help is appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: So you just want to sort the output based on second column?

Answer (score 8):

Let's create a function to transpose a file (make rows become columns, and columns become rows):

```
transpose () {
  awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i,NR]=$i; max=(max<NF?NF:max)}
        END {for (i=1; i<=max; i++)
              {for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) 
                  printf "%s%s", a[i,j], (j<NR?OFS:ORS)
              }
        }'
}
```

This just loads all the data into a bidimensional array `a[line,column]` and then prints it back as `a[column,line]`, so that it transposes the given input. The wrapper `transpose () { }` is used to store it as a bash function. You just need to copy paste it in your shell (or in `~/.bashrc` if you want it to be a permanent function, available any time you open a session).

Then, by using it, we can easily solve the problem by using `sort -n -k2`: sort numerically based on column 2. Then, transpose back.

```
$ cat a | transpose | sort -n -k2 | transpose
john sarah mark
5 10 20
z x y
```

In case you want to have a nice format as final output, just pipe to `column` like this:

```
$ cat a | transpose | sort -n -k2 | transpose | column -t
john  sarah  mark
5     10     20
z     x      y
```

Step by step:

```
$ cat a | transpose 
sarah 10 x
mark 20 y
john 5 z
$ cat a | transpose | sort -n -k2
john 5 z
sarah 10 x
mark 20 y
$ cat a | transpose | sort -n -k2 | transpose 
john sarah mark
5 10 20
z x y
```

Comment: This works really well (thank you) but it seems computationally very expensive on a large file. If I want to do it more quickly am I stuck with reading it into my own data structure and sorting on it there?

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507231/how-to-sort-columns-using-bash-script#25507231), this would sort the columns by the first row:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="$1"

order=$((for i in $(head -1 $input); do echo $i; done) | nl | sort -k2 | cut -f1)

grep ^ $input | (while read line
  do
    read -a columns <<< "${line%"${line##*[![:space:]]}"}"

    orderedline=()
    for i in ${order[@]}
    do
      orderedline+=("${columns[$i - 1]}")
    done
    line=$(printf "\t%s" "${orderedline[@]}")
    echo ${line:1}
  done)
```

To sort by second row, replace `head -1 $input` with `head -2 $input | tail -1`. If the sort should be numeric, put in `sort -n -k2` instead of `sort -k2`.

Answer (score 1):

Good one-liner gets the job done:

`perl -ane '$,=" "; print sort @F; print "\n";' file`

I found it here: http://www.unix.com/unix-for-advanced-and-expert-users/36039-horizontal-sorting-lines-file-sed-implementation.html

Comment: This sorts each line individually, rather than moving the data of the columns so that the first line is sorted.