# Transpose till "n"th column into row:

Tags: awk

I would like to transpose column to row by every 3rd column.

Input.txt

```
Name
Age
Place
aa
22
xx
bb
33
yy
cc
44
zz
....
....
```

Desired Output

```
Name,Age,Place
aa,22,xx
bb,33,yy
cc,44,zz
```

I have tried below command and in-complete

```
awk '
{
  for(c = 1; c <= NR; c++)    { a[c]=$c }
}
END {
  for(r = 1; r <= NR; r++) {
    for(t = 1; t <= 3; t++) {
      printf("%s ", a[c])
    }
    print ","
  }
}'  Input.txt
```

Looking for your suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many good tools for this.

#### This awk!

```
$ awk 'ORS=NR%3?",":RS' file
Name,Age,Place
aa,22,xx
bb,33,yy
cc,44,zz
```

It sets the output field separator as `,` whenever the line is not multiple of 3. This way, it joins every group of 3 lines.

More info in [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).

#### xargs

```
$ xargs -n3 <file
Name Age Place
aa 22 xx
bb 33 yy
cc 44 zz
```

This gets the input in blocks of `X` items, defined by `-n X`. Then you can replace spaces with commas with `tr` or `sed`.

#### paste

```
$ paste -d"," - - - <file
Name,Age,Place
aa,22,xx
bb,33,yy
cc,44,zz
```

This joins every 3 input and uses delimiter `,` as separator.

---

Regarding transpose itself, I wrote a snippet a while ago in [Using bash to sort data horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25062537/1983854):

```
transpose () {
  awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i,NR]=$i; max=(max<NF?NF:max)}
        END {for (i=1; i<=max; i++)
              {for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) 
                  printf "%s%s", a[i,j], (j<NR?OFS:ORS)
              }
        }'
}
```