# Copy a row from multiple files and paste as column in a new file

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have few files as:

```
ifile1.txt       ifile2.txt       ifile3.txt
3  5  2  2       1  2  1  3       4  3  4  1 
1  4  2  1       1  3  0  2       5  3  1  5 
4  6  5  2       2  5  5  1       3  4  3  1 
5  5  7  1       0  0  1  1       4  3  4  0 
2  3  2  4       3  2  4  1       3  1  2  1
```

I need to copy 4th row from each file and paste as columns in ofile.txt as:

```
ofile.txt
5    0   4
5    0   3
7    1   4
1    1   0
```

I was able to do it in the following way, but looking for a direct/short method.

I first converted the rows of each file into columns using `awk`

```
awk '{ 
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
a[NR,i] = $i
}
}
NF>p { p = NF }
END {    
for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
str=a[1,j]
for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
    str=str" "a[i,j];
}
print str
}
}' ifile1.txt > ofile1.txt
```

Then I used used `paste` command as

```
paste ofile* > ofile.txt
```

Finally used `awk` again to print the required columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Deepu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2105110/deepu) mentions in [his good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31937529/1983854), saying `FNR==4` suffices to print the fourth line on every file:

```
awk 'FNR==4' files*
```

With this you get something like

```
5  5  7  1
0  0  1  1
4  3  4  0
```

And now you just need to transpose the array. For this I created a little script [some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25062537/1983854), that I named `transpose` (very good at names, I know):

```
transpose () {
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i,NR]=$i; max=(max<NF?NF:max)}
        END {for (i=1; i<=max; i++)
            {for (j=1; j<=NR; j++) 
                printf "%s%s", a[i,j], (j<NR?OFS:ORS)
            }
        }'
}
```

All together, you just need to say:

```
$ awk 'FNR==4' f* | transpose
5 0 4
5 0 3
7 1 4
1 1 0
```

Note you can set input and output field separators if you wish to keep format (I guess they are tab separated right now).

Comment: If you have it available (BSD variants, at least), `rs` can also be used to transpose. `awk 'FNR==4' f*.txt | rs -T`

Comment: @jas interesting, I didn't know this tool. It is a pity, though, that `yum install rs` does not find anything in my computer : (

Comment: Indeed, `rs` looks to be the opposite of portable! Mac OS X has it so I thought it worth mentioning, but for anything other than a one-off on a compatible system your works-everywhere script is the way to go.

Comment: `+1` and I deleted my answer as it was very similar (mainly I just pulled the `FNR==4` inside the awk script). One thing to note is that `(j<NR?OFS:ORS)` would be better than `(j==NR?RS:FS)` in that it's using the output separators when producing output instead of the input separators and it has FS stated before RS in the code which co-insides with the order you'll output them and so slightly improves the clarity. FWIW I personally get confused when writing code that loops through rows and columns so I tend to name the variables `colNr` and `rowNr` (or `c` and `r`) for my own benefit at least!

Comment: @EdMorton oh, thanks a lot for the suggestions! I will introduce them and deploy the changes, because I am using this script in many answers now : D (Please keep the comment so I can revisit later!)

Answer (score 2):

`awk 'FNR == 4 {print}'` will print the fourth row from a text file.

You can use the redirection operator `>` and concatenation operator `>>` to append the data from different files.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is regular, this is another way of transposing

```
tr ' ' '\n' <file | pr -"$n"ts" "
```

where `n` is the number of rows in your file (columns in transposed version) `n` can be assigned as

```
 n=$(wc -l file | cut -d" " -f1)
```

Your script can be simplified to

```
 awk 'FNR==4' ifile*.txt > temp
 n=$(wc -l temp | cut -d" " -f1)
 tr ' ' '\n' <temp | pr -"$n"ts" " > ofile.txt
```