# sorting rows of a data file with Linux

Tags: linux, sorting, row

I would like to sort the lines of a data file (each line idependent from each other) from the first character. For example, if I have a data file

```
1   0.1     0.6     0.4
2   0.5     0.2     0.3
3   1.0     0.2     0.8
```

I would like to end with something like

```
1   0.6     0.4     0.1
2   0.5     0.3     0.2
3   1.0     0.8     0.2
```

I have tried to do it using the *sort* command, but it sorts the columns (not the line). Transposing the data file +*sort* could be also a good solution (I don't know any easy way for transposing datafiles).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062169/using-bash-to-sort-data-horizontally maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lawne '
    print join "\t", $F[0], sort { $b <=> $a } @F[1..$#F]
' < input > output
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits the line on whitespace into the @F array
- `-l` adds newlines to `print`

See [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort), [join](http://p3rl.org/join)
.

Comment: So useful and powerful command. Thank you for your answer, it definitively solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Or to read input line by line, use `tr` and `sort` like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
while read -r line; do
    echo $line | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -k1,1nr -k2 | tr '\n' '\t' >> output
    echo >> output
done < input
```

`tr ' ' '\n'` is to convert row to column.